# How can I have dropdown box with the list and inserted value as default for UPDATE In PHP.?

Tags: php, mysql

First I would like to update the records.
I created dropdown box which has values from mySQL FROM SELECT statemet it's working fine with one previously selected database entry. 
but what I would like to have another values for the modification wich i have in another table.

**DROP DOWN FOR THE UPDATE from order table value.**

```
    echo '<div class = "MediaType" >'; //Start class Media Type
    echo '<strong><label for="rate">Media Type</label></strong>';
    echo '<br/><br/>' ;

        $sql = "SELECT `media_type` FROM `order` where `po_number` = '".$ponumber."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "<select class='dropdownsize' name='media_type[]' tabindex='$k'>";

                echo "<option value='" . $row['media_type'] . "'>" . $row['media_type'] . "</option>";
                echo '</select>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }

echo '</div>'; //End Class Media Type
```

It's give me value "ONLINE" in dropdown which I selected and Inserted during the Insert process.

**DROP DOWN FOR INSERT Page from media_type table**

```
echo '<div class = "MediaType" >'; //Start class Media Type
    echo '<strong><label for="rate">Media Type</label></strong>';
    echo '<br/><br/>' ;

        //for loop for dropdown from user index//
        for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
        {
        $sql = "SELECT media_type FROM media_type";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
            echo "<select class='dropdownsize' name='media_type[]' tabindex='$k'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['media_type'] . "'>" . $row['media_type'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<br/>';
        }
echo '</div>'; //End Class Media Type
```

table name = "media_type"
values = "TV","ONLINE","Roller",Banner","Roll Over"

I want to have this "media_type" values in my update drop box as same as the insert dropbox so enduser can modify entry with media_type values as Insert. but when it's display 1st time then default values of dropbox should be same as previous entered data.

sorry my question is confusing.
What is the best way to doing.?
Any help will be appreciate.
thank You

Comment: I did not understand your question clearly, do you want to fetch data from media_type and order table at the same time?

Comment: yes.. with the default value for dropdown from order table

Comment: Order table where i saved my insert records and media_type is my drop down general list

Comment: Can i see your tables or at least do they have any values used on all tables? I mean id for media_type or something common on both tables.

Comment: Unfortunately i Dont have common fields but i can create.

Comment: I have only media_type field in media_type table

Comment: in order table i have 1 field for media_type which stores value from user during insert and others fields like date,index,rate,qty etc..

Comment: I'm sorry but i really can't understand your question, can you edit your question and add details about your tables please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please go through [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)

As per your existing code, you can modify your *DROP DOWN FOR THE UPDATE from order table value.* with the below code..Here we are running a second while loop to get the desired results..

Also please note that it may not be the right way when there are thousands of options to be appended in terms of performance..

```
echo '<div class = "MediaType" >'; //Start class Media Type
    echo '<strong><label for="rate">Media Type</label></strong>';
    echo '<br/><br/>' ;

        $sql = "SELECT `media_type` FROM `order` where `po_number` = '".$ponumber."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "<select class='dropdownsize' name='media_type[]' tabindex='$k'>";

                echo "<option value='" . $row['media_type'] . "'>" . $row['media_type'] . "</option>";


        $sql2 = "SELECT media_type FROM media_type";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
            {
            echo "<option value='" . $row2['media_type'] . "'>" . $row2['media_type'] . "</option>";
            }



                echo '</select>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }

echo '</div>'; //End Class Media Type
```